# Facebook Sponsored/Ad Posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, posts

I recently saw Sponsored posts by a page. Current this appears only for pages from Canada. Is there any way we can get these posts using Facebook graph API? I assume Facebook should give it since these are publicly visible.
Check our few Canadian pages:
https://www.facebook.com/pg/cialiscanada/ads/
https://www.facebook.com/pg/chevroletcanada/ads/

PS: These pages may not be visible outside Canada.

Comment: Just because you can see something on facebook.com doesn't mean it is available in the API. What is available in the API you can read about at https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Comment: That's true. Couldn't find it in the documentation though.